# How to disable the text "Be the first of your friends to like this" beside a FB button

Tags: facebook

I want a simple Like button. How can I obtain that. I don't want any viewcount nor people displayed besides my like button.

Comment: i use layout button_count, does not show faces but does show a simple count on the right hand side.  NOTE: you can not modify the button in the DOM for violation of Facebook Usage Terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet may be to use the [Facebook like button code generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and:

1. Set the Layout Style to `button_count`
2. Uncheck the `Send Button` option
3. Uncheck the `Show Faces` option

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the attribute **show-faces** to **false** like this:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="false"></fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter answer: Use:

```
data-layout="button_count"
```

in your element. This will display '0' rather than the longer prompt. There is unfortunately no way to display nothing at beside the button, however you can [use CSS/JS tricks to hide the count](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count).

This could be as simple as:

```
$('div.fb-like').width(48).css({'overflow':'hidden'})
```

but see the question linked above for more detailed information.